# About vb.net "checkedchanged" and "click" in radiobuttons

Tags: vb.net

I want to know the difference between the two events. Like, there is a project I'm working on in vb.net where I've included timer and I want to stop the timer once the user choose any of the radiobuttons. In which event should I write the code, checkedchanged or click? And why?

Comment: In most cases it sounds like either one would do what you need.  But keep in mind that users can navigate the UI with the keyboard, so they may change the checked state without clicking.  If you want to respond to a chance in the checked state, checkchanged sounds like the clear answer.

Comment: You can read about the differences on MSDN

Answer (score 4):

A "Click" is any time the mouse button is clicked on a control.  This can happen for an already selected option, or an area of the control that doesn't change any values.  "CheckChanged" events fire only when the selection changes, even if the selection is changed by code or with the keyboard.

Typically the CheckChanged event is the one you'll want to use, unless you're specifically responding to mouse clicks.